# New instance of List when casting

Tags: java

Does this line:

```
List params = (List) hashMap.get(key);
```

create a new list, or just appends it to the list?

Here is how I use the code:

```
ParameterCache cache = ParameterCache.getInstance();
        HashMap hashMap = cache.getAllParameters(ParameterCodeConstants.PARAMETER_DORF_REGION, false);
        ArrayList regionIdList=new ArrayList();
        Set keys = hashMap.keySet();
        Iterator it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            BigDecimal key = (BigDecimal) it.next();
            List params = (List) hashMap.get(key);
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                ParameterDTO paramDTO = (ParameterDTO) params.get(0);

                String textValue = paramDTO.getParameterTextValue();
                if(textValue.equals(region_id)){
                    regionIdList.add(paramDTO.getRegion());
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: List params = (List) hashMap.get(key); 
I just wanted to know whether params list will be created newly in the while loop each time or just the values from the map will be appended say the DTOs according to the code, or each time in the loop the DTO will be added to the zeroth position of the List.

Comment: Thank You All...Just found out the answer after trying it out myself...as discussed it is just a reference to the DTO object and gets refreshed each time the loop is processed..there is no appending taking place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this line create a new list or just appends to the list
>
> ```
> List params = (List) hashMap.get(key);
> ```

None of this - only an assignment is taking place here. The value associated with `key` in this map is supposed to be a reference to an existing `List` object (or `null`), and this is returned by `get`. This reference is then assigned to `params`.

Since the local variable `params` did not exist prior to this declaration, there is no list to append anything to anyway.

Comment: @Peter---you mean to say the DTO object will get placed at the 0th position each time .And after the loop is finished the next DTO reference is placed at the 0th position replacing the previous DTO refernce.

Answer (score 4):

An expression such as

```
(List) hashMap.get(key);
```

will *not* create a new list. It will return a copy of the List-reference stored in the map.

(And I don't see any calls to `add` so I don't see how anything could get appended either.)

Answer (score 0):

In the line `List params = (List) hashMap.get(key);`, params will be the return value of hashmap.get(key). So no, there is no appending happening there.